# How Can i resize the image? (cv2.drawMatchesKnn) in colab

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, google-colaboratory

```
img1=cv2.imread('/content/datamy/notre.jpg',0)
img2=cv2.imread('/content/datamy/notre2.jpg',0)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(500)
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.5*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

This is part of the code.
result image is [image]

I can't see the matched line because it's too small. Is there a way to print the size larger?(Like the original size.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `cv2.resize`?

`img1` size is greater than the `img2`, so you could get the `img1`'s height and width:

```py
(h, w) = img1.shape[:2]
```

and resize with `img2`

```py
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (w, h))
```

Result:

---

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('notre.jpg', 0)
img2 = cv2.imread('notre2.jpg', 0)

(h, w) = img1.shape[:2]
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (w, h))

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(500)
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.5*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I figured out how. '''fig, axs=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(18,12))
axs.imshow(img3,cmap='gray')''' It was this code. Thank you.